# What is shunt field resistance in a DC Generator?

Tags: resistance

Is the "shunt field resistance" the resistance of the  coils in a shunt generator?

Googling https://www.google.com/search?q=%22shunt+field+resistance%22&oq=%22shunt+field+resistance%22&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 didn't give any helpful results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a great explanation in the [NI link](http://www.ni.com/white-paper/14922/en/) of your search.

The total field resistance is made up of the field coil pair (in series) and one (occasionally 2) limit resistor. In old DC car generators there was typically 1 resistor, which set low current and when shorted out, high current output.  Controlled by a voltage sensing relay and an overcurrent relay.